# How to limit amount of selected in custom select menu in javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, css

### How to limit amount of selected in custom select menu in javascript?

I want to make a custom select menu where you can select items in it.
This is my code for now:

```js
class CustomSelect {
  constructor(originalSelect) {
    this.originalSelect = originalSelect;
    this.customSelect = document.createElement("div");
    this.customSelect.classList.add("select");

    this.originalSelect.querySelectorAll("option").forEach((optionElement) => {
      const itemElement = document.createElement("div");

      itemElement.classList.add("select__item");
      itemElement.textContent = optionElement.textContent;
      this.customSelect.appendChild(itemElement);

      if (optionElement.selected) {
        this._select(itemElement);
      }

      itemElement.addEventListener("click", () => {
        if (
          this.originalSelect.multiple &&
          itemElement.classList.contains("select__item--selected")
        ) {
          this._deselect(itemElement);
        } else {
          this._select(itemElement);
        }
      });
    });

    this.originalSelect.insertAdjacentElement("afterend", this.customSelect);
    this.originalSelect.style.display = "none";
  }

  _select(itemElement) {
    const index = Array.from(this.customSelect.children).indexOf(itemElement);

    if (!this.originalSelect.multiple) {
      this.customSelect.querySelectorAll(".select__item").forEach((el) => {
        el.classList.remove("select__item--selected");
      });
    }

    this.originalSelect.querySelectorAll("option")[index].selected = true;
    itemElement.classList.add("select__item--selected");
  }

  _deselect(itemElement) {
    const index = Array.from(this.customSelect.children).indexOf(itemElement);

    this.originalSelect.querySelectorAll("option")[index].selected = false;
    itemElement.classList.remove("select__item--selected");
  }
}

document.querySelectorAll(".custom-select").forEach((selectElement) => {
  new CustomSelect(selectElement);
});
```

```css
.select {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(3, 1fr);
  max-width: 300px;
  gap: 1px;
}

.select__item {
  padding: 10px;
  cursor: pointer;
  font-family: "Heebo", sans-serif;
  text-align: center;
  border-radius: 3px;
  background: #eeeeee;
  transition: background 0.1s;
}

.select__item--selected {
  background: #009578;
  color: #ffffff;
}
```

```html
<select name="language" class="custom-select" multiple>
  <option value="html">HTML</option>
  <option value="css">CSS</option>
  <option value="javascript">JavaScript</option>
  <option value="python">Python</option>
  <option value="sql">SQL</option>
  <option value="kotlin">Kotlin</option>
</select>
```

What it does now is fine, I just want to add the limitation so that you can only select two items. This is because I want to make a game similar to memory.

Does anyone know how to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just count selected items, create variable `let count = 0;`, add count increase on selection add check on count before selecting.

```js
class CustomSelect {
  constructor(originalSelect) {
    this.originalSelect = originalSelect;
    this.customSelect = document.createElement("div");
    this.customSelect.classList.add("select");

    let count = 0;

    this.originalSelect.querySelectorAll("option").forEach((optionElement) => {
      const itemElement = document.createElement("div");

      itemElement.classList.add("select__item");
      itemElement.textContent = optionElement.textContent;
      this.customSelect.appendChild(itemElement);

      if (optionElement.selected) {
        this._select(itemElement);
      }

      itemElement.addEventListener("click", () => {
        if (
          this.originalSelect.multiple &&
          itemElement.classList.contains("select__item--selected")
        ) {
          this._deselect(itemElement);
          count--;
        } else if (count < 2) {
          this._select(itemElement);
          count++;
        }
      });
    });

    this.originalSelect.insertAdjacentElement("afterend", this.customSelect);
    this.originalSelect.style.display = "none";
  }

  _select(itemElement) {
    const index = Array.from(this.customSelect.children).indexOf(itemElement);

    if (!this.originalSelect.multiple) {
      this.customSelect.querySelectorAll(".select__item").forEach((el) => {
        el.classList.remove("select__item--selected");
      });
    }

    this.originalSelect.querySelectorAll("option")[index].selected = true;
    itemElement.classList.add("select__item--selected");
  }

  _deselect(itemElement) {
    const index = Array.from(this.customSelect.children).indexOf(itemElement);

    this.originalSelect.querySelectorAll("option")[index].selected = false;
    itemElement.classList.remove("select__item--selected");
  }
}

document.querySelectorAll(".custom-select").forEach((selectElement) => {
  new CustomSelect(selectElement);
});
```

```css
.select {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(3, 1fr);
  max-width: 300px;
  gap: 1px;
}

.select__item {
  padding: 10px;
  cursor: pointer;
  font-family: "Heebo", sans-serif;
  text-align: center;
  border-radius: 3px;
  background: #eeeeee;
  transition: background 0.1s;
}

.select__item--selected {
  background: #009578;
  color: #ffffff;
}
```

```html
<select name="language" class="custom-select" multiple>
  <option value="html">HTML</option>
  <option value="css">CSS</option>
  <option value="javascript">JavaScript</option>
  <option value="python">Python</option>
  <option value="sql">SQL</option>
  <option value="kotlin">Kotlin</option>
</select>
```